# How can I delete my Hunch account?

Tags: account-management

I want to delete my Hunch.com account that I created with facebook because I've also create an account with my twitter login. How can I delete my Hunch.com account?

Comment: Hunch.com closed down in 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Log in to Hunch.com using the account you want to delete
2. Click `Settings` in the upper right
3. Scroll down and click the "Delete my account" link near the bottom of the page
4. Fill out and submit the deletion form